# Asp.net core 5, using Identity, how do I change the default redirect of the [Authorize] Attribute?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, .net-5, asp.net5

The `[Authorize]` is wonderful for locking pages down but I am building a new product with few users and it makes no sense that it directs people to Login, because there is no one to login yet. It should direct them to Register instead.

But I am struggling to find an easy way to do that without a ton of middleware.

Comment: I don't know if there is a better way but I'd create a custom authorize attribute that redirects to your registration page. The answer submitted is a better answer

Comment: `Authorize` doesn't redirect. As the name suggests, it deals with *authorization*, not authentication. `Authorize` specifies which already authenticated users should be allowed to access and endpoint. Redirection is performed, if needed by the *authentication* middleware, ASP.NET Core Identity

Answer (score 2):

You can change the `LoginPath` on start up, but I suspect this does not answer your question because when enough users exists then what happens?

To change the login path you can add:

```
 services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
         .AddCookie(cookieOptions =>
         {
            cookieOptions.LoginPath = "/register";
            cookieOptions.AccessDeniedPath = "/account/denied";
            cookieOptions.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(120);
         });
```

However if you are wanting a switch when you have reached a critical mass then this will not suffice.

**EDIT** one approach could be something like:

Create a `loginOrRegister` page. Then on this page hit the database (or whatever you use to see whether you have hit critical mass or its a *known user* based on a cookie) and then either

- Redirect to Login

OR

- Rediect to register

Comment: Right, that could cause lots of issues if we force the loginpath to be the register path. Sucks that its not just a param right there though, redirect on unauthorized or something.

Comment: Most sites just kinda say on login page  `To create an account click here` :)

Comment: Yea for sure and I have that but you know how users are these days, they will just click out, they are so lazy they wont click one extra link to sign up.

Comment: Another point to consider is **HOW** many **new** people will actually hit a secure page when they first come to your site? You may be over thinking it

Comment: @LouieBacaj you're overthinking it.  Every web site, including this one, redirects you to a `Login` page that has a `Register` button, or a `Register` page that has a `Login` button. The actual page and workflow is the same in both cases - you get redirected to a login page. What changes is the content of that page

Comment: @LouieBacaj users will land on the anonymous landing page when they visit the site the first time, not one of the members-only pages. If you want to have a members-only landing page, you probably need *two different* landing pages, an anonymous and a secure one.

Comment: Understand what you guys are saying.

But it would still be nice to be able to easily change where it redirects to.